# Outlook ICS / iCalendar: No Field ("To:") for further Attendees when Organizer is set?

Tags: outlook, icalendar, appointment

**My goal:**

- **(Step 1)** Open ICS file in Outlook, so the user can send a generated meeting/appointment to recipients of his or her choice. Therefore I use the PUBLISH method. It is pretty much what is explained here: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2446#section-4.1.1
- **(Step 2)** Let user update scheduled meeting via ICS (this should be 4.1.2 in the RFC).

**Requirements deadlock each other:**

- In order to update a scheduled meeting, I need to set an ORGANIZER.
- If ORGANIZER is set though, there will be no field to enter recipients (Step 1).

**This is what my ICS looks like on first publish:**

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:MyProg
METHOD:PUBLISH
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:{9D3C6B93-D935-44EA-A4CD-498900BCFEFD}
SEQUENCE:1
PRIORITY:5
ATTENDEE;RSVP=TRUE:mailto: 
DTSTAMP:20121107T183153Z
DTSTART:20121107T190000Z
DTEND:20121107T193000Z
SUMMARY:This is the Subjectline
LOCATION:Room 1
DESCRIPTION:Hello, please join my presentation.
ORGANIZER:mailto:abc@bcd.com
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Purpose of the line starting with ATTENDEE is to make the "To:" field appear.
If the line with ORGANIZER is omitted, Step 2, the update, won't work.
If ORGANIZER is set, there will be no field to fill in recipients...

**This is what my ICS looks like on second publish to update the first publish:**

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:MyProg
METHOD:PUBLISH
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:{9D3C6B93-D935-44EA-A4CD-498900BCFEFD}
SEQUENCE:0
PRIORITY:5
ATTENDEE;RSVP=TRUE:mailto: 
DTSTAMP:20121107T184400Z
DTSTART:20121107T190000Z
DTEND:20121107T193000Z
SUMMARY:This is the MODIFIED SUBJECT
LOCATION:Room 1
DESCRIPTION:Hello, please join my presentation.
ORGANIZER:mailto:abc@bcd.com
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Has equal UID and incremented SEQUENCE and DTSTAMP as required! Won't work if ORGANIZER is omitted.

---

Are there any suggestions for me to fulfill my goals Step 1 & 2 with update capability and without losing the recipients field "To:"??

Thank you so much in advance!

---

Comment: Did you end up solving this issue? I am facing exacly the same deadlock under http://stackoverflow.com/q/28819645/2721750 I can't fathom how a requirement to have an `ORGANIZER` can be imposed on the creator of the meeting, especially when there is no way to know for the software which created an ICS who the organizer should be, while OL knows exactly who is the organizer!!!