# What should be in the ICS file in order to create a meeting invite to the multiple attendees in Outlook?

Tags: outlook, icalendar

What I am trying to achieve is in the screenshot below: It is an Outlook meeting invite, which has the To field pre-popultated with the specified names, the Send button just says 'Send' and its reminder is set to 15 minutes.

[image]

I created the following ICS file and expected that it would create the required invite, but it is doing something different: the To list is blank, as is the reminder and the Send button says 'Send Update'.

As this is supposed to be created from an open to the public web page with no log in, `ORGANIZER` cannot be set and OL is supposed to know who they are.

[image]

What am I doing wrong in the ICS file?
Are there any other methods besides `PUBLISH` and `REQUEST` that OL supports?

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
METHOD:PUBLISH
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:somethingunique
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20150302
DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20150302
ATTENDEE;CN="First Last";ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;RSVP=TRUE:MAILTO:"first_last@test.com"
ATTENDEE;CN="John Doe";ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;RSVP=TRUE:MAILTO:"jdoe@test.com"
ATTENDEE;CN="Et Cetera";ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;RSVP=TRUE:MAILTO:"etc@test.com"
BEGIN:VALARM
TRIGGER:-PT15M
ACTION:DISPLAY;
DESCRIPTION:Reminder
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

I also tried changing to use the `METHOD:REQUEST`, but it opens as what looks like a reply to an invite with no possibility to change the subject/location or add more attendees:

[image]

When `REQUEST` method is used there are a few issues with the invite: it is not editable, it is not actually created in OL, clicking 'No response required' actually deletes the invite and I end up with noting (there is no way to save and send the invite).

Answer (score 4):

If it helps anyone, here are the changes that partially worked:

1. No method should be used
2. No quotes allowed around the email addresses!
3. `;VALUE=DATE` is not supported (OL 2010) and time component has to be there.
4. Alarm is not set even though method `REQUEST` would set it.

ICS code that created a meeting as required:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:somethinguniquehere204832901
DTSTART:20150303T100000
DTEND:20150303T100000
ATTENDEE:john_doe@test.com
ATTENDEE:jane_doe@test.com
BEGIN:VALARM
TRIGGER:-PT15M
ACTION:DISPLAY
DESCRIPTION:Reminder
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

When that is processed, the form has a `Send Update` button, which when clicked, creates a meeting and sends the invites. This still does not look like a brand new OL meeting request that the users are accustomed with.

Answer (score 3):

The first issues: I'm spotting are:

1. your iCalendar event *must* have an organizer.
2. It's also missing a `UID`.
3. `METHOD:PUBLISH` is wrong. It should probably be `REQUEST` or not be in there at all, depending on the context.
4. `ACTIONDISPLAY` is not valid, it's missing a colon.

I would recommend taking a proper CalDAV / iCalendar client application (so not Outlook), create an event with invites there and then export that event. Then you can use that as a template for how the iCalendar object *should* look.

Comment: Thanks for pitching in! I looked at all the examples showing the organizer too, but I cannot use it. The reason being that I am supposed to create a meeting invite for someone who is not logged into the system - for the public. Their OL should know who they are (and that works with REQUEST method). Adding UID does not change anything. Removing alarm completely does neither. This is supposed to be just as trivial as creating a new email by clicking a `mailto:` link, but apparently this task is unnecessarily complicated and nothing changed in the last 10 or so years.

Comment: Also I exported the event as per above and it appeared as method REQUEST, which I cannot use as stated in the question - it does not open as an editable request. As OL is used here, other clients can hardly help.

Comment: The problem you are trying to solve is not really addressed by iCalendar. You're not really looking to create an event, but rather a template for an event. You're partially achieving this, but it's a bit of a 'hack' in some ways. Any behavior you would rely on for outlook would be non-standard.

Comment: Making the event appear read-only as soon as you add an organizer therefore kinda makes sense. Outlook follows the standards correctly apparently. Without an organizer, outlook _should_ ignore attendees.

Comment: It ignores the attendees even with an organizer in PUBLISH and does not ignore in REQUEST. If that is a standard, it is a really bad one.

Comment: What you are doing is non-standard, so whatever behavior you are seeing is outlook specific and also non-standard.

Comment: It's just too bad that the creators of the standard did not think of such rudimentary simple use of ICS: to create a new meeting invite. But I did (almost) successfully use your suggestion to remove the method - it worked, with some cosmetic side effects but worked!

Comment: Well, standards need people such as yourself to bring this up. Generally standards are developed to scratch an itch. If there are more people like you and specifically need this, you can pitch it and write the standard. It's open to everyone.

Comment: I'm actually involved in that process, so from my perspective it sounds a bit like : I wish somebody did my job for me ;)

Comment: Having followed @ajeh 's answer (Mar 3 '15), I wanted to note here in the comments on this answer that when you're creating the invite to be opened in an Outlook client, you DON"T need to specify the organizer. When you send the invite "update", it assumes you're the organizer and the messages go out that way. My guess is that if you leave off the organizer, Outlook will always assume when opening an ICS file, that the current user is the organizer.

Comment: @DavidNavarre that might be true, but it's definitely a violation of the standard.

Comment: Unhelpful standard.

Comment: @ajeh without that standard, there would be no calendar invitations across systems.

Comment: The standard applies to completed calendar invitations. What we're talking about is fragmentary calendar invitations that open in the UI, so that the user can fill out more information and their calendar application can complete the other parameters to bring it in line with the standard before it is saved or sent to attendees. If someone was creating a calendar invitation in their chosen application and had not yet selected the date and time, it wouldn't meet the standard, would it?